# Listen to key press when the program is in the background

Tags: vb.net, background, keypress

I am currently working with a program which is supposed to run in the background but also check if "mod + o" is pressed then do something. But I cannot figure out how a vb.net program can listen to key presses when the program is not *Selected* / *Opened*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use P/Invocation to be able to use WinAPI's [**GetAsyncKeyState() function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx), then check that in a timer.

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Short
End Function

Const KeyDownBit As Integer = &H8000

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LWin) And KeyDownBit) = KeyDownBit AndAlso (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.O) And KeyDownBit) = KeyDownBit Then
        'Do whatever you want when 'Mod + O' is held down.
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT:**

To make the code only execute one time per key press, you can add a little `While`-loop to run until either of the buttons are released (add it **inside** your `If`-statement):

```
While GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LWin) AndAlso GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.O)
End While
```

This will stop your code from executing more than once while you hold the keys down.

When using this in a Console Application just replace every `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` and `Keys` with `ConsoleKey`, and replace `LWin` with `LeftWindows`.

Comment: I do not know the number, but its name is `System.ConsoleKeyInfo`, heres the script I used to find it out:

    `Dim modKey = ReadKey()`
    `WriteLine(modKey)`

Comment: @RichardOlsenSandberg : The name isn't enough. Also `System.ConsoleKeyInfo` is a structure containing information about a keypress, not a single key. Use this method instead: `WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(modKey.Key))` and you'll get the number.

Comment: I am also having a little bit of trouble on how i do this for vb.net console application..

Comment: What are you having trouble with? You can just replace the timer with an infinitely looping thread and you should be good to go.

Comment: `Public Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Short
End Function`

Comment: `<DllImport("user32.dll")> _` is not defined: `DllImport`

Comment: @RichardOlsenSandberg : On the very top of your code file, add: `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices`.

Comment: What about `System.Windows.Forms.Keys is not defined`

Comment: Also it needs the function to return something, can i just add `Return True`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116239/discussion-between-richard-olsen-sandberg-and-visual-vincent).

Comment: @RichardOlsenSandberg : Either import `System.Windows.Forms` as a reference to your project, or simply change it to `System.ConsoleKey` (my last suggestion isn't tested though. Some keycodes seem to be the same but I am not sure. It should work for the basics).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @VisualVincent. Quick question, does it particularly matter what interval you set the Timer to? Is there a disadvantage to having the Timer fire too often?

Comment: @LeoKing : The Interval does matter, yes. There's no problem setting it to 1 (it can only do approximately 50 ms anyway), but you need it to fire often or else you won't catch all the key strokes.

Comment: @LeoKing : After a certain amount of time (a few 50-100 ms) `GetAsyncKeyState()` will no longer report the key as pressed, which is why you need to check often.

Comment: Okay. Is there a simple way to override key combinations in another program, or does this require code particular to the program? E.g. if I wanted to set a key combination to Ctrl+O and make it so that when my program was open and I am focused on MS Word, it wouldn't start to Open a file in Word. If this is exceedingly complex, don't worry about it, I just won't bother implementing this in my program.

Comment: @LeoKing : `GetAsyncKeyState()` merely checks if a key is down, up or neither. The code that executes when the criteria is met is whatever you write in your application.

Comment: @LeoKing : Are you saying you want to stop the other application from opening the "Open file" dialog? If so, that requires you to hook into the application and intercept the key stroke. It's a bit more advanced and cannot be solved using `GetAsyncKeyState`. -- A good start is to Google "VB.NET Keyboard hook".