# VB.Net Hidden Program Hotkeys

Tags: vb.net, keypress, hotkeys

Is there a way to register hotkeys to toggle a form from an invisible(hidden) program? I’ve tired normal methods and they only work when the form is either visible, or the active window. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.KeyPreview = True
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    Me.ShowIcon = False
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub
```

This is the code that hides the program.

Comment: What is this "invisible/hidden" program?  I don't know how one could answer this question without knowing more about that program and whether or not or how you could modify the program to manipulate your form...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen to key press when the program is in the background process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153300/listen-to-key-press-when-the-program-is-in-the-background-process)

Comment: If you were to add this load event that hides the program and runs it as a process. But it also makes the hotkeys not work either.

'    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.KeyPreview = True
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        Me.ShowIcon = False
        Me.Visible = False
    End Sub'

Comment: @Visual Vincent The methods mentioned in that article only work for unhidden programs.

Comment: No it does not only work for "unhidden programs". Did you even read the title? I answered the question myself, I've used that method MANY times. `GetAsyncKeyState()` works without needing your program to be visible/have focus.

Comment: @Visual Vincent I did read it. In fact, that's how I added the hotkeys to my program, someone else pointed me to that article in a past question. But when I run that code in the example above to hide the program. the hotkeys no longer work.

Comment: Could you please show us the relevant code on _how_ you create the hotkeys, and how you check them? The code you show so far doesn't give us much to go on. If a `Timer` doesn't work because you hide your form, then you should consider using a thread.

Comment: @Visual Vincent You also commented this morning about a call method from the example program where that snippet is from.

Comment: This doesn't 'hide' anything. This just makes it invisible to the user. It won't change the behavior of `GetAsyncKeyState()` as Vincent has suggested or just about anything else.

Comment: @Visual Vincent I didn't use a timer because it drives the size of the program up when its ran over a long period of time. Do you have slack of something? id be happy to send you the whole example file.

Comment: @Ares but it does change the behavior of the hotkeys, i.e. making them no longer work. If I comment out the code and make the program visible they work fine.

Comment: Could you show us the hotkey code you've tried?

Comment: I have submitted a requested edit - @gregknight, in the future, please refrain from addressing specific users in your answer - that should have been a comment. I'm moving it to a comment: "@Visual Vincent the article that you said this is in duplicate of only works for unhidden programs."

Comment: @gregknight : But in your other question you never use `GetAsyncKeyState()`, you say it doesn't work so I wanted to see what you've tried _using that specific function_. -- However, I'm glad you solved it now!

Comment: @Ares  Sorry, I thought I had to edit it to include the reason why it wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: @gregknight No problem :). In the future, just talk about why it's not a duplicate of another _question_. Others coming to the post will want to see if it's a duplicate, and if it is, what it's a duplicate of. If it's not a duplicate, explain why it's not a duplicate of that _question._ And welcome to SO! Don't be discouraged by the downvotes, just try and make every question better than the last.

Comment: @Visual Vincent this is actually the third time I reworded the question lol. the first one had the function that include the GetAsyncKeyState() method. Those question actually got upvoted, figured the question everyone hates yields the answer I have been searching for. Thanks you too for your help.

Comment: @gregknight : Not that I did much, but you're welcome for what I did, I guess ;). Currently Ares  is the savior of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Global Hotkeys. Just make sure you unregister when the program closes.

From a MSDN article that helped me in the past:

> Firstly, you need to know the Virtual-Key Codes.
>
> http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx   You can then
>   P/Invoke RegisterHotKey/UnregisterHotKey APIs to register/Unregister
>   the hotkey.   Code sample: Register multiple hotkeys such as Alt+D,
>   Alt+C, etc.
>
> ```
> Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
>
> Public Class Form1
>
>     Public Const MOD_ALT As Integer = &H1 'Alt key
>     Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312
>
>     <DllImport("User32.dll")> _
>     Public Shared Function RegisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
>                         ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer, _
>                         ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
>     End Function
>
>     <DllImport("User32.dll")> _
>     Public Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
>                         ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
>     End Function
>
>     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
>                         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
>         RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_ALT, Keys.D)
>         RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 200, MOD_ALT, Keys.C)
>     End Sub
>
>     Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
>         If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
>             Dim id As IntPtr = m.WParam
>             Select Case (id.ToString)
>                 Case "100"
>                     MessageBox.Show("You pressed ALT+D key combination")
>                 Case "200"
>                     MessageBox.Show("You pressed ALT+C key combination")
>             End Select
>         End If
>         MyBase.WndProc(m)
>     End Sub
>
>     Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
>                         ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) _
>                         Handles MyBase.FormClosing
>         UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100)
>         UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 200)
>     End Sub
>
> End Class
> ```