# vb.net hotkey registration with 2 modifiers

Tags: vb.net, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I’m working on a project that I need to register a hot key for, any I’m running into a wall trying to figure out how to add another letter modifier to the hotkey registrar. For example, CTRL+SHIFT, A+B. As of right now the code that I’m running works, but it only accepts one letter modifier. Can anyone show me where I’m going wrong? I was hoping it was as simple as adding the ‘And’ operant or ‘+’ to concatenate it as a string. Here’s an example of what I have that works.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

Public Const MOD_ALT As Integer = &H1
Public Const MOD_SHIFT As Integer = &H4
Public Const MOD_CTRL As Integer = &H2
Public Const MOD_WIN As Integer = &H8
Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312

<DllImport("User32.dll")>
Public Shared Function RegisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer, ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("User32.dll")>
Public Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_ALT Or MOD_SHIFT, Keys.A)'alt+shift,A

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
        Dim id As IntPtr = m.WParam
        Select Case (id.ToString)
            Case "100"
                MessageBox.Show("You pressed alt+shift, A", "Hello", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        End Select

    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100)
End Sub

End Class
```

Like I said, this works so far, CTRL+SHIFT, A. What I’d like to do is modify it to accept an additional modifier key like, CTRL+SHIFT, A+B. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I've never used the `RegisterHotKey` method so I'd do it by [**using GetAsyncKeyState()**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153300/listen-to-key-press-when-the-program-is-in-the-background/38154826#38154826).

Comment: I think we went through this before lol. It’s a background application so that doesn't work that great. From what I’m reading I don't think this it is possible to register an additional letter modifier with the windows API.

Comment: `I think we went through this before` What do you mean? I don't recognize you (new account?). -- And I don't know what `RegisterHotKey` can do, but using `GetAsyncKeyState()` you will be able to specify how many buttons to press, and _**it will definitely**_ work in a background application _(which is what the whole question I linked you to is about)_.

Comment: You don't have to use `GetAsyncKeyState()` if you don't want to :), but as far as _I know_ that's the best solution for you so far (unless you find a way to add another modifier to `RegisterHotKey`).

Comment: @VisualVincent  Yeah I made a new account because I got banned for asking crappy questions lol. From what I remember, from our last discussion, you could not register global hotkeys with the GetAsyncKeyState() method.

Comment: Well you don't _register_ the hotkeys. You just continuously check if a key or a key combination is pressed (done in a timer, a thread, a task, or whatever you like). But it works perfectly fine for applications running in the background _**(so yes, in a way it is global)**_. There's a complete working example in the link I gave you in my first comment.