# Minimize and maximize program with key press

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make my program minimize and maximize upon a key press (I'm using the h key).

```
 Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    Select Case e.KeyChar
        Case "h"
            If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
                Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
            ElseIf Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
                Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
End Class
```

I don't see why it won' work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen to key press when the program is in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153300/listen-to-key-press-when-the-program-is-in-the-background)

Comment: What is it doing instead?

Comment: @Brandon : Probably nothing. I suspect this is related to his form not having focus when he's pressing the key.

Comment: @VisualVincent I didn't really read through the code but yeah it wont work when the form's minimzed. That's PInvoke territory.

Comment: @Brandon : As previously flagged... :)

Answer (score 0):

hmm maybe its not working because your form is not in a maximize state or in minimize state. in short maybe your form is in a normal state. Try this step sir.

1st: set the key preview of the form to True.
then in you code:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
 Select Case e.KeyChar
    Case "h"
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        ElseIf Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        else
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized 'add this.
        End If
 End Select
End Sub
```

if this code dind't work try to transfer this to key down event.
hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: if this help you or find this as answer then mark it so that people will not be confused. or if you have your own answer and solve it by your self then post it for some research options