# Autoclicker keybinds minimized VB

Tags: vb.net

How do I do so when I minimize the program and press F9 to start and stop?

I have already made the clicker but want to make hotkeys/shortcuts to start.

I use Visual Basic

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please work to improve this question. We don't know what code you already have, or where you're stuck.

Comment: Use the Form.KeyPress event I guess. Not sure what you mean by start and stop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen to key press when the program is in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153300/listen-to-key-press-when-the-program-is-in-the-background)

Comment: So, you want to make a global hotkey (F9) to your program? You'll need APIs for that. For your reference, see [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/it-IT/c1a24688-d844-4adc-9d85-416a7158c6ba/faq-how-do-i-register-a-hotkey-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I would believe you need a KeyLogger. I found some code [here](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/KeyLogger.php) and used that to make a working example:

```
Public Class Form1

    ' Creates variables and functions
    Dim T As New Timer() With {.Enabled = True, .Interval = 1}
    Dim key As Integer
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Keys) As Short

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler T.Tick, AddressOf T_Tick
    End Sub

    Private Sub T_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        For i = 1 To 255
            key = 0
            key = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
            ' If this key is being pressed
            If key = -32767 Then
                ' Writes the key that was pressed
                Console.WriteLine(Chr(i))
                If i = 120 Then
                    ' This happens when F9 is pressed
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub

End Class
```

Hope this helped!
~Nic

Comment: I'm just curious how you get that he _"want to make **hotkeys/shortcuts**"_ into that he would want a keylogger?

Comment: I believe it is the only way (or one of the only ways) to detect when keys are pressed when the form is not active. Perhaps you can show me wrong, though; there might be other ways to do this I am not aware of.

Comment: Yeah there are other ways :). A keylogger logs _every_ pressed key and is considered malware. However the code in your answer utilizes `GetAsyncKeyState()` which is one way of doing it (for instance see my answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153300/listen-to-key-press-when-the-program-is-in-the-background)).

Comment: Three ways I know to create hotkeys are: **1)** Using `GetAsyncKeyState()`, **2)** Using `Register-/UnregisterHotkey`, or: **3)** Using a global keyboard hook. -- The latter is the most complicated and most unnecessary (but still possible) method of the three.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this after you add `KeyPreview = True` in Form Load.
Add an event called keydown and add the following code:

```
If e.keycode = Keys.F9 Then
  Button1.PerformClick()
End If
```