# Vb.net see if the back-slash key is pressed when form is not focused

Tags: vb.net, input, keystroke

I have been trying to work this out all day, i want the script to detect a key press (specifically '\') even when the form is minimised.

So far i have a thread running as a background task, but seem to cant make it detect whether i have pressed the back slash key or not. one way about this would be to detect ASCII characters, but not sure how i would construct the within a thread.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf MyBackgroundThread)

Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    thread.Start()
End Sub

    Sub MyBackgroundThread()
        Do
            If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Then
                SendKeys.SendWait("{q}")
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
                SendKeys.SendWait("{q}")
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

The code above works for shift, but not for oem-back slash, which is one of the other available selections. if you guys have a solution that'd be great, thx guys...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen to key press when the program is in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153300/listen-to-key-press-when-the-program-is-in-the-background)

Comment: You might not want to use the `Activated` event as that's fired whenever the form gains focus. Use the [**`Load` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) instead if you want it to execute only the first time the form is about to be shown.